# How can I convert this if statement to an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, arrow-functions

I have an function with an if statement that says:

```
function reflect() {
    if (number_a >= 600) {
         ball_velocity_a = -ball_velocity_a }
    if (number_b >= 600) {
         ball_velocity_b = -ball_velocity_b
}}
```

and I'm trying to convert this function into arrow function

```
const deflect = () => number_a >= 600 ? ball_velocity_a = -ball_velocity_a :
```

but I'm not sure what to put after the `:` as `ball_velocity_b` is conditioned with `number_b` instead of `number_a`. I'm really new to arrow functions and would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: ball_velocity_a = number_a >= 600 ? -ball_velocity_a : -ball_velocity_b

Comment: Tight a function to handle only two specific variables is not the way we should do programming. Use function arguments `reflect (a, b)` or `= (a, b) =>`. Use `balls` Object to store your balls... etc etc

Comment: Apart from your function looking "edgy", what else would that accomplish?

Comment: Consider `ball_velocity_a *= number_a >= 600? -1 : 1;`, similarly for `ball_velocity_b`. I can't see any point in using an arrow function.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a readable pice of code into not so easy to understandable code? You don't get any performance benefit out of that change.

Answer (score 2):

```
var deflect = () => { 
ball_velocity_a = number_a >= 600 ? -ball_velocity_a : ball_velocity_a;
ball_velocity_b = number_b >= 600 ? -ball_velocity_b : ball_velocity_b;
};
```

Comment: you forgot somehow about ball b?

Comment: @JonasWilms I edit answers, when not in edit queue or *hot*. I've been bashed not once for editing in sync with OA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the comma operator to chain conditions, also as you don't have an `else` branch it doesnt make sense to use a ternary. Here is the code that is equal to your function:

```
 const deflect = () => (
   number_a >= 600 && (ball_velocity_a = -ball_velocity_a),
   number_b >= 600 && (ball_velocity_b = -ball_velocity_b),
   undefined
 );
```

But IMO that is actually way worse than your original function.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid the use of globals, hard-coded constants inside helper functions and misleading function names (calling reflect/deflect if no reflect/deflect actually occurs).

```
const adjustVelocityComponent = (velocity, position, maxPosition) => {
  if (position >= maxPosition) // probably also check if position <= 0
    return -velocity;
  return velocity;
};

ball_velocity_a = adjustVelocityComponent(ball_velocity_a, number_a, 600);
ball_velocity_b = adjustVelocityComponent(ball_velocity_b, number_b, 600);
```